# Katalon Studio - java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal method name in class CustomKeywords

Tags: java, katalon

I am using Katalon Studio version 8.2.5 for automating my test cases.

While I try to run a test case, an error occurs randomly stating "java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal method name "myMethodName" in class CustomKeywords".
I have checked that there are no compilation errors in my package/ class where the method is created.
Note that even if I am not not using this custom keyword in my test case and calling it, the test case fails to run because of the existence of the custom keyword I have created in my project.
Note that also the "@Keyword" annotation is preceding the custom keyword.

I have read that this bug is raised in newer versions of Katalon Studio (7.9 and greater), due to upgrading Eclipse framework (including Groovy-Eclipse plugin). And that it is was fixed in version 8.0
Though I am using version 8.2.5, but error still appears and i can't manage to identify the reason.
I have also tried to do many workarounds such as deleting .cache folder, libs folder, etc.
But error still exists.

If anyone has previously faced this issue and knows how it can be solved, I really appreciate informing me the solution :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and it's gone by changing the class name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).